# Dynamically remove Component from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am adding and deleting components dynamically in a `JPanel`.
Adding and deleting functionality works fine but when I delete the component it deletes the last component rather than the component to be deleted.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please post your code so we can help.

Comment: For better help sooner, include an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: Are you using the method "public void remove(int index)" instead of "public void remove(Component comp)"? Post an SSCCE if you want a better answer.

Comment: +1 for `CardLayout` - makes life much easier if you have a pool of components to show at different times.  Thanks for reminding me of it, @Andrew.

Answer (score 24):

Interestingly enough I am coming across the same issue and I am surprised people are upvoting the other answer, as he is clearly asking about **dynamically** created Components, not components already created under a variable name which is obtainable, instead of anonymously created objects.

The answer is pretty simple. Use
[getComponents()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) to iterate through an array of components added to the JPanel. Find the kind of component you want to remove, using [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java) for example. In my example, I remove any JCheckBoxes added to my JPanel.

[Make sure to revalidate and repaint your panel, otherwise changes will not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001087/jpanel-removeall-doesnt-get-rid-of-previous-components)

Component is from [java.awt.Component.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

```
//Get the components in the panel
Component[] componentList = panelName.getComponents();

//Loop through the components
for(Component c : componentList){

    //Find the components you want to remove
    if(c instanceof JCheckBox){

        //Remove it
        clientPanel.remove(c);
    }
}

//IMPORTANT
panelName.revalidate();
panelName.repaint();
```

Comment: The revalidate bit is what worked for me. What was interesting to me was, after initializing the panel with a particular component, I didn't need repaint() on the first revalidate(). On subsequent revalidations, I needed to repaint() as well.

Answer (score 11):

Using the method `Container.remove(Component)`, you can remove any component from the container.  For example:

```
JPanel j = new JPanel();

JButton btn1 = new JButton();

JButton btn2 = new JButton();

j.add(btn1);

j.add(btn2);

j.remove(btn1);
```