# Selenium/Java/Junit - Getting the driver/browser being used while running the test

Tags: java, selenium

Is there any way to programmatically get the driver (ie. IE/Firefox/Chrome etc) being used while running the test?

Ie. by a way other than "remembering" what driver you called at the beginning - some method or property of Webdriver that could be accessed while running the program?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question as you use the initialized webdriver (such as Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(..)) throughout your tests. The "driver" instance contains all the information you need. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: Since my test framework is fairly large, and cross-browser testing is required, the initialization of the webdriver is conditional and happens in a part of the framework that is not accessible from every other part of the framework. But since some html behaviour is browser dependant, being able to get what browser is being used during a certain run/for a certain test, would be pretty helpful in terms of deciding method behaviour, and I was hoping there was a way to do this.

Comment: Well you could always use an isInstanceOf to find which driver was instantiated. But you should also consider making this a configurable property that can be accessed everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option1 - to store the driver in a global variable or create a public method to get the driver type in the not so accessible part of your framework.

Option2 - check if the driver is an instance of a particular webdriver class.
Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java)

Comment: Just saw this one! Yes. Exactly.