# How to identify objects in array using instanceOf method and for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So basically I have this java assignment which has six classes in it **(Rectangle, Circle, Cylinder, Box, ShapesABSTester)** for the driver I needed to create an array and then use a for loop to identify the objects in the array using the **instanceOf** method.

**This is what I have for the loop**

```
for(int i = 0; 1 < myShapes.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(myShapes[i].toString());

        }
```

This works perfectly fine in that it goes through the list and prints out all of the output I need by getting the toString method from the other classes, but apparently I have to use the instanceOf method to achieve this. I have searched on here and google and haven't found anything close to what I need, so hoping someone could help me out on the correct syntax.

**As the instructions state**

Using a for loop examine each item in the array with the instanceOf method to determine
if the object is a cylinder, circle, box, or rectangle

i. Print out the type of object and the object’s toString()

ii. Only “type” an object once

iii. If an object is a cylinder then do not call it a circle as well

iv. If an object is a box then do not call it a rectangle as well

**And thus the output should be something like**

Object 0 is a rectangle and then print the toString method

Object 1 is a box

Object 2 is a circle

Object 3 is a cylinder

Comment: I say, "go for it!" Seriously, you haven't even posted an attempt yet, and so your question is premature. Please come back *after* you've at least attempted this, and then if still stuck, show us your attempt, and ask a specific question.

Comment: Can you post all the classes?

Comment: I agree with @hovercraft that this question is somewhat offensive

Comment: @Leo: Not offensive of course, not in the least, but he's cheating himself by not trying first, for that's how he learns. Or if he did try, he's not getting as good help as he could have if he showed us what he did so we can see what he's doing wrong, and thus help correct his assumptions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this is an attempt, I already have all the classes done, just needed the last part

Comment: @Leo: now he's getting sort of offensive. He's begging the spoon-feeder to feed him some more. Not good.

Comment: No it's not. You've not tried anything with instanceof yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < myShapes.length; i++)
{
     System.out.print("Object " + i + " is a");

     if(myShapes[i] instanceof Rectangle)
          System.out.print(" rectangle: ");

     else if(myShapes[i] instanceof Circle)
          System.out.print(" circle: ");

     else if(myShapes[i] instanceof Box)
          System.out.print(" box: ");

     else if(myShapes[i] instanceof Cylinder)
          System.out.print(" cylinder: ");

     System.out.println(myShapes[i].toString());

}
```

Comment: Thank you that was what I was looking for, how to write it with the array outputting the index

Comment: @user3015009: are you going to ask him to do your whole assignment for you? Surely you can try **something**.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Like I just said to you, I already have it done, I just needed the last part. Geeze lay off and go heckle someone else for not showing so called effort in "your" eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Second result in google...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java

```
if( object instanceof Rectangle) {
   System.out.println("object is rectangle");
}
```