# How to check if Fragment implements an interface

Tags: android, interface

In my main Activity I've set up a interface `CentreKeyPress`, and I have 4 Fragments in a ViewPager, and a few of them implement this, a few don't. The interface has an `onBack` method, for when the back button is pressed. Here's my current code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.contact_view_pager);

        List<Fragment> frags = adapter.getFragments();

        try {
            ((CentreKeyPress) frags.get(pager.getCurrentItem())).onBack();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Is a try/catch loop the best way to check if a Fragment implements the interface, or is there some kind of method that I can use to check if it implements it? Or, alternatively, could my Fragment handle onKeyUp themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use keyword  `INSTANCEOF` and check if fragments are instance of interface
you can check this to: [use of "Instance of" in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether fragment is a `instanceof` the given fragment

```
if(frags.get(pager.getCurrentItem()) instanceof CentreKeyPress){
    //fragment implements CentreKeyPress
}
```