# Java generics unchecked casts - wildcard bounds

Tags: java, generics, warnings

I'm trying to understand generics, but I block at wildcard bounds and casts. For instance:

```
List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<PositiveInteger> p = new ArrayList<PositiveInteger>();
p.add(new PositiveInteger(10));
l = p;
NegativeInteger ni = (NegativeInteger) l.get(0);// runtime java.lang.ClassCastException:
System.out.println(ni);
```

NegativeNumber and PositiveNumber both extend Number. So the question is why there is no warning at compile-time when casting the element from the list into a NegativeNumber ? Is there a way to prevent this type of exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the same thing will happen if you'll do:

```
Object a;
Integer b = new Integer(5);
a=b
Double c = (Double)a;
```

ClassCastException happend because you are trying to convert a class to another class that isn't the parent/Child class

as to the question about preventing it:

the compiler don't know what will be in `l` in run time. but you can use `List<PositiveInteger>` instead of wildcard to tell the compiler what is going to be in `l`. if you have to use `List<? extends Number>` you can create a method that tries to cast the object, that way you can tell if the object is `List<PositiveInteger>` or `List<NegativeInteger>` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java):

```
if(l instanceof List<NegativeInteger>){
   //Do something
}
```

so if i change your code accordingly:

```
List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<PositiveInteger> p = new ArrayList<PositiveInteger>();
p.add(new PositiveInteger(10));
l = p;
Object ni = l.get(0);
if(ni instanceof NegativeInteger){
   NegativeInteger tmp = (NegativeInteger)ni;
   System.out.println(ni);
}
```

Comment: The use of instanceof was something I wanted to avoid. It seems puzzling to me that there is no warning when casting even in the simple form like your first code snippet.

Comment: @Fram why do you want to avoid instaceof? i use it all the time. it's a lot better then catching exception on cast all the time

Answer (score 0):

When you define the Generic type using wildcards like `<? extends Number>` you should not cast the objects into the subclasses of Number because the generic type is saying that you will get an instance of subclasses of `Number`. Similar to this  chunk of code:

```
Number n = new PositiveInteger(10);
NegativeInteger  ni = (NegativeInteger ) n;
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you're casting, you tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing", so it won't complain as long as it's possible to cast the object (NegativeNumber extends Number -> ok).

If you really need to cast (which you want to avoid; generics is all about compile-time safty and avoiding "unsafe" casts), you could check it first like this:

```
Number number =  l.get(0);
if (number instanceof NegativeInteger){
    NegativeInteger ni = (NegativeInteger) l.get(0);
    ...
}
```