# How to know which activity CustomAdapter is working on?

Tags: android, android-activity, custom-adapter

I have gone across many demos on different `CustomAdapter` but neither demo shows how we can actually get which activity we are using adapter for, inside the adapter. Right now I am using this approach for adapter

```
private Activity activity;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d, Resources resLocal) {
    activity = a;
    ....
}
```

At `Activity a` I can actually get context but failed to get that on which activity I can use its function. While activity is still opened so there must be something to communicate to its functions. Anyway using following technique by me is totally reckless

```
try {
    ((HomeActivity) activity).onItemClick(mPosition); // function in other activity
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    ((PlayActivity) activity).onItemClick(mPosition); // function in other activity
}
```

I am **using same `CustomAdapter` class for more than one activity** so using try-catch to automatically find which method will not raise exception as I still do not know about the parent activity.

If anyway we can get to know about it that will be great!

Thanks for reading, Cheers!

Comment: have you tried instanceof?

Comment: I have not tried anything like this but if it can excludes the need of that `try-catch` I will be happy to hear from you. Thanks

Comment: exactly, it will, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java) will tell how to use them, remind me to post as answer if it helps. or another way could be create a String with the same variable name and assign the it to the name of the class in both activities and check if they match..

Comment: Yes, you got it! `if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {...}` It worked just as I want, a bit compromise as I have to do if-else everywhere but its certainly better than try-catch. You solved a big problem for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can post it as answer and I will be happy to mark it right. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `instanceof`

more info from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)