# Check if Elements in an Array are of a SubClass in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

let's assume that I want to check if values within an Object array are of the superclass or subclass let's say for instance that my super class is Called Animal, I declare an array of type Animal

```
Animal myAnimals[] = new Animal[];
```

Now suppose that there are subclasses of Animal like Lion, Tiger, Elephant, etc. If I were to loop through an array, how would I differentiate the subclasses (Lion, Tiger, etc.) from the superclass Animal? Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want the names of the particular class? You can print the name. If you have a set number to test, you can use `instanceof`. What are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: There is instanceof, of course, but using instanceof is a design smell. You should instead use polymorphism. Call a method on Animal, and the subclass method will be called and do what is appropriate for that kind of animal.

Comment: Could explain what exactly it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)

> At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true if [...]
>   the reference could be cast (§15.16) to the ReferenceType without
>   raising a ClassCastException.

```
for (Animal a : myAnimals) {
    if (a instanceof Lion) System.out.println("Lion");
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @YassinHajaj already said you can use the [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java) operator:

```
 for (Animal animal : animals) {

     if (animal instanceof Tiger) {

           Tiger tiger = (Tiger) animal;
     }
 }
```

However this results in unstructured code, besides this is hard to maintain. I personally prefer an more object oriented way.

As @JBNizet suggested in a comment you can use [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading). That's good but not perfect: you will need to change the implementation of all animal classes in order to add some logic.

---

### Visitor pattern

However if you combine this with the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This will become very powerful because you can separate the logic into a visitor class:

```
interface AnimalVisitor {

    void visitLion(Lion lion);
    void visitFish(Fish fish);

    // Gets called when animal does not override the accept method:
    void visitDefault(Animal animal); 
}

class Animal {

    public void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitDefault(this);
    }
}

class Fish extends Animal {
    
    @Override
    public void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitFish(this);
    }
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    
    @Override
    public void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitLion(this);
    }
}
```

Then you can easily replace your loop with something like this:

```
AnimalVisitor visitor = new AnimalVisitor() {

    @Override
    public void visitLion(Lion lion) {
        // Do something with lion
    }
    
    @Override
    public void visitFish(Fish fish) {
        // Do something with fish
    }
}

for (Animal animal : animals) {
    animal.accept(visitor);
}
```

---

We can even take this one step further:

### Reflective visitors

Since it is annoying to add for every different kind of animal an specific `visitAnimal` method, we can make use of [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) to avoid this! This will result in smaller and cleaner code:

```
interface Visitable { }

class Animal implements Visitable {

    // No accept method
}

class Fish extends Animal {}
class Goldfish extends Fish {}
class Shark extends Fish {}


// Take for example this visitor:

class BittenByVisitor extends ReflectiveVisitor {

    
    private Surfer surfer;

    public BitByVisitor(surfer) {
        this.surfer = surfer;
    }
        
    // We only care about the sharks:

    public void visit(Shark shark) {

        surfer.die();
    }


    // Any other fish is just the same:

    public void visit(Fish fish) {

        surface.decreaseHealthBy(1);
    }

    // It also works with interfaces:
    public void visit(VerySmallFish fish) {

        // Do nothing by purpose!
    }
}
```

And here an implementation of the reflective visitor:

```
abstract class ReflectiveVisitor {
    
    public void visit(Visitable v) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method m = findMethod(v);

        try {
            m.invoke(this, new Object[] { v });
        }

        catch ( IllegalAccessException e1 ) { /* code handling */ }
        catch ( InvocationTargetException e2 ) { /* code handling */ }
    }

    private Method findMethod(Visitable v) throws NoSuchMethodException {

        String methodName = "visit";
        Class visitable = v.getClass();

        while ( isAncestorOf("Visitable", visitable) {

            Class visitor = getClass();

            while ( isAncestorOf("Visitor", visitor) {

                try {
                    Method m = visitor.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[]{visitable});
                    return m;
                } catch ( NoSuchMethodException e ) {
                    visitor = visitor.getSuperclass();
                }
            }

            visitable = visitable.getSuperclass();
        }

        String errMsg = "put error message here";
        throw new NoSuchMethodException(errMsg);
    }

    private boolean isAncestorOf(String ancestorName, Class descendant) {

        try {
            return Class.forName(ancestorName).isAssignableFrom(descendant);
        }
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) { /* code handling */ }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Source code is taken from [this paper](http://hillside.net/europlop/HillsideEurope/Papers/EuroPLoP2001/2001_MaiEtAl_ReflectiveVisitorPattern.pdf).

I personally like to use a reflective visitor which avoids the `Visitable` class. You can define it like this:

```
class ReflectiveVisitor<T> {

    public void visit(T visitable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate every element and check the subtype by using instanceof..