# Store different kinds of objects in order and make use of them according to their properties

Tags: java, arraylist

I have seen that one can use 
`ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();`
in order to generate a list that may contain different kinds of objects (such as object A and object B). I also have seen answers that state one can search what kind of objects are contained in that list by using

```
for (Object obj : objectList){
     if(obj.getClass() == A.class){
         doSomething();
     } 
}
```

However, its has been mentioned that this is not a very elegant approach. On the other hand, if I use an abstract class or an interface I need to have the same methods for object A and object B. For example if A.get() returns an integer, B.get() must also return an integer. But what I want is that the method making use of my objectList will do something different for different objects contained in the objectList. So A.get() may return an integer, B.get() may return a string.

So what I want to ask you guys is what is the best way to do this? Its not difficult to write a "hack", but I want to write good code.

Thanks.

Comment: I think a generic object can be used, if you have same method name

Comment: use instanceof operator => `if( obj instanceof A)` instead of `obj.getClass() == A.class`, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java

Comment: Why do I get a -1 rating for this post? I do use proper grammar, I did not just copy some large section of code into my question, I made my question well understandable (all of you understood my question immediately). So whats the matter?! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If your method `doSomething()` is highly relying on the type of object, you could move it to those objects and use an interface.

```
public interface Foo {
    void doSomething();
}

public class A implements Foo {
    public void doSomething() {
        // do something
    }
}


for (Foo obj : objectList){
    obj.doSomething();
}
```

How elegant this is strongly depends on what is done in `doSomething()`. If it is really different for each object, this approach might work. If it is similar, try identifying only the differences and encapsulate them in the interface like shown above.

Comment: thanks. the problem is I have to write into a large section of code that has been done by somebody else - and its not such a good section of code so I try my best not to make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
public  class BaseClass {
    public void method() {}
}
```

2

```
public class ChildOne extends BaseClass {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("inside ChildOne");
    }
}
```

3

```
public class ChildTwo extends BaseClass {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("inside ChildTwo");
    }
}
```

4

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BaseClass> obj = new LinkedList<>();
        obj.add(new ChildOne());
        obj.add(new ChildTwo());

        for (BaseClass b : obj) {
            ((BaseClass) b).method();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `method` is not implemented in `BaseClass`, then make it an abstract class or an interface.

Comment: actually i was trying to keep it simple as I can , and yes interface approach is good

Comment: no, not like this. because in my case both classes ChildOne and ChildTwo return different values (in your example both return void).

Comment: if they have same return type , then use `print(b.method)` its same thing