# calling sub methods on various objects in an array list

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of animals on land. All animals are of different classes, that extend an abstract superclass called `Animal`. They all have methods such as `eat`, `walk`, `sleep`, etc., but only the `Bird` class has the method `fly`.

How can I call the `fly` method on all `Bird` objects in the ArrayList?

```
public class Land{
    ArrayList<Animal> landAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    Land(Bird bird, Bird bird2, Bird bird3, Cat cat, Mouse mouse, Dog dog, Dog dog2){
        landAnimals.add(bird); 
        landAnimals.add(cat); 
        landAnimals.add(mouse);
        landAnimals.add(bird2); 
        landAnimals.add(dog); 
        landAnimals.add(bird3);
        landAnimals.add(dog2);
    } 

    public void animalsWalk(){ 
        int size=landAnimals.size(); 
        for (int count=0; count<size; count++){ 
            landAnimals.walk(); 
        } 
    }  

    public void birdsFly(){ 
        //How do I make birds in the arraylist fly?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to iterate over the contents of `landAnimals`. You can do that with a [standard `for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```java
for(int i = 0; i < landAnimals.size(); i++) {
    Animal animal = landAnimals.get(i);
    // TODO
}
```

Then you need to determine whether each particular animal object is of the `Bird` class. You can do that with the [`instanceof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java) operator.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < landAnimals.size(); i++) {
    Animal animal = landAnimals.get(i);
    if(animal instanceof Bird) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Then you need to [*cast*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java) `animal` to the `Bird` type, before you can call its `fly` method. Once you have done that, you can make the standard method call.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < landAnimals.size(); i++) {
    Animal animal = landAnimals.get(i);
    if(animal instanceof Bird) {
        ((Bird) animal).fly();
    }
}
```