# Check if current activity is required activity (same parent)

Tags: android

I have DrawerParent class which is basically a drawer. And, say, two activities inherited from DrawerParent. What I want is to not re-open same activity if it is already running. For such thing I need to somehow check whether this activity is running or not. It works like this in drawer:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
            finish();

        } else ...
```

And I don't know how to check it. Thank you.

== Edit ==
Making group in layout and adding selectable="single" not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running that code on the activity, you can compare using:

```
if (!(this instanceof ActivityToBeOpened)) {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityToBeOpened.class));
   finish();
}
```

You can get more info about `instanceof` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526896/4244598).

Hope it helps!

Comment: It absolutely works! Thank you so much, have a great day :)

Comment: I'm trying, can't do it in 3 more minutes. Sure I won't forget about your help :)