# Do something if the list contains two objects of class

Tags: java, list

I have a list containing different commands all implemented the same interface (ICommand). These commands are each classes containing information on what the spesific command should do.

I want to be able to tell if the list contains two spesific commands, and do something if they appear together.

For example:

```
List<ICommand> commandList = getCommandList(); // not important how the list is made
```

pseudo code comming up:

```
if ( commandList contains HelpCommand.class && WriteHelpToFileCommand.class )

then do something (write the help to a file)

else do something else (print the help to console)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the stream API to check for this.

```
if(commandList.stream().anyMatch(e -> HelpCommand.class.isInstance(e)) && commandList.stream().anyMatch(e -> WriteHelpToFileCommand.class.isInstance(e))) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something entirely different by changing some of the system design. The Java 8 streams was a perfect match. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'instanceof' operator to check if your list element is of class HelpCommand and/or WriteHelpToFileCommand.

It's well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java)

Comment: I would like to check this without looping through the whole list. In that case I would have to loop through the list twice: first time to check whether the list contains the commands, and the other time to actually run the commands.