# Android Room with entity inheritance

Tags: android, android-room

I have a room database with a entity with some subclass.

Each subclass, has some methods overrides and I need get that overrided methods when I use the entities.

Any way to get all entities and each as correct subclass implementations?

Example:

> base class -> Person
>
> sublcass1 -> Teacher
>
> sublcass2 -> Student

And when get all persons, any each is a diferents class (some are Student, some are Teacher...)

> var persons = getAllPersons();
>
> if (person[0] as Student)
>
> ....
>
> if (person[1] as Teacher)
>
> ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java

Comment: Sorry. The cuestion is not how use "instance of" in jave or "is" in kotlin. The question is how to get that room create instance of subclass instead of instance of base class

Comment: I don't see what else the question would be, can you please clarify

Comment: If a save a Student class instance, when room return it, it return as Person instance, not as Student instance.