# How can I access a child method in an ArrayList of parent type?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on a problem wherein I need to create a virtual Dessert Shoppe with Java classes. I need to print a sort of receipt that is formatted in a certain way, and I have a class Sundae. I also have an ArrayList of type DessertItem (superclass to Ice Cream, which is superclass to Sundae). I want to access a method in Sundae from this ArrayList, but it won't let me as the ArrayList type is of DessertItem.

Here is the DessertItem class:

```
public abstract class DessertItem {
  
  protected String name;
  
  public DessertItem() {
    this("");
  }

  public DessertItem(String name) {
    if (name.length() <= DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE)
      this.name = name;
    else 
      this.name = name.substring(0,DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE);
  }

  public final String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public abstract int getCost();
}
```

The Checkout class (which has the receipt):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Checkout {
    
    ArrayList<DessertItem> dessertItems = new ArrayList<DessertItem>();

    public int cost;

    public void clear() {
        dessertItems.clear();
    }

    public void enterItem(DessertItem item) {
        dessertItems.add(item);
    }

    public int numberOfItems() {
        return dessertItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String reciept = "      " + DessertShoppe.STORE_NAME + "\n" +
                        "      --------------------\n" +
                        " \n";
        cost = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dessertItems.size(); i++) {
            if (dessertItems.get(i) instanceof IceCream) {
                reciept = reciept + " " + dessertItems.get(i).getName() + "       " + Integer.toString(dessertItems.get(i).getCost()) + "\n";
            } else if (dessertItems.get(i) instanceof Sundae) {
                reciept = reciept + (" Unfinished\n");
//              string.concat(" " + dessertItems.get(i).getName()).concat("       " + Integer.toString(dessertItems.get(i).getCost())).concat("\n");
            } else if (dessertItems.get(i) instanceof Candy) {
//              string.concat(" " + dessertItems.get(i).getName()).concat("       " + Integer.toString(dessertItems.get(i).getCost())).concat("\n");
            } else if (dessertItems.get(i) instanceof Cookie) {
                reciept = reciept + (" Unfinished\n");
//              string.concat(" " + dessertItems.get(i).getName()).concat("       " + Integer.toString(dessertItems.get(i).getCost())).concat("\n");
            }

            cost += dessertItems.get(i).getCost();
        }

        double taxRate = DessertShoppe.TAX_RATE;
        double tax = taxRate / 100;

        reciept.concat(" \n");
        reciept.concat(" Tax                         " + tax + "\n");
        reciept.concat(" Total Cost                " + (cost * (1 + tax)) + "\n");
        
        return reciept;
    }

    public int totalCost() {
        cost = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dessertItems.size(); i++) {
            cost += dessertItems.get(i).getCost();
        }

        return cost;
    }

    public int totalTax() {
        cost = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dessertItems.size(); i++) {
            cost += dessertItems.get(i).getCost();
        }
        double taxRate = DessertShoppe.TAX_RATE;
        double tax = taxRate / 100;

        return (int) Math.round(cost * tax);
    }
}
```

The Sundae class:

```
public class Sundae extends IceCream {

    public String toppingName;
    public int cost;
    public int toppingCost;

    public Sundae() {
        this("", 0, "", 0);
    }

    public Sundae(String newName, int newCost, String newToppingName, int newToppingCost) {
        if (newName.length() <= DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE)
            this.name = newName;
        else
            this.name = newName.substring(0,DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE);
       
        if (newToppingName.length() <= DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE)
            this.toppingName = newToppingName;
        else
            this.toppingName = newToppingName.substring(0,DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE);

        this.cost = newCost;
        this.toppingCost = newToppingCost;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCost() {
        return cost + toppingCost;
    }

    public String getToppingName() {
        return toppingName;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the item for `instaceof` the subclass, then cast it to the subclass if it matches.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java#7526896

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried casting to Sundae?

```
((Sundae)(dessertItems.get(i))).getName()
```

Something along these lines. This should work althought I have only tried it in the opposite direction: Casting a child to a parent.

You can read more about this at the [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) documentation by Oracle themselves.

Good luck with you project!

Comment: yes i have, doesnt work since sundae is not directly under DessertItem class, it is under ice cream which is under DessertItem

Comment: Theoretically, it should work thanks to polymorphism, like `Parent var = new Child()` for example. Do you have an error or exception log, @Ronitrocket?

Comment: I dont know what an exception log is but there isn't any errors

Comment: When i debug it, when the index of the array is an Sundae object that was passed into the arrayList, it goes to ice cream, which is the parent class of sundae, so i suspect its autocasted or something

Comment: when i debug it the for loop never goes to the instanceof sundae if statement, whenever there is a sundae object it goes to ice cream leading me to believe its autocasted to icecream