# Is List<View> worth it?

Tags: java, android, android-view

## Problem

I Have a custom activity that load graphics from an XML file, where i have a lot of Buttons, Images and Text.

## My Implementation Planning

For implementation i want to use android classes like `ImageButton`, `TextView` and `ImageView`.

I have thinking to use a `List<View>` for looping all `View` objects and inflating into a `RelativeLayout`.

#### My doubt

Is better a `List<View>` or `List<ImageButton>`, `List<TextView>` and `List<ImageView>`?

Method implementation in `ImageButton` or `ImageView` (Like `onClick` or some other event), is lost when i convert it to a `View` object?

#### Example of code i planned:

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(getContext());

//Implementation of methods and events...
List<View> list = new ArrayList<View>;
list.add(imageButton);
```

Comment: That depends 100% on what you want to do - if you need some method that is only defined in the subclasses then you should split the lists, if you only use methods defined in `View` then use a `List<View>`.

Comment: The list holds only references of your components. If you create an ImageButton for exmaple, set a click listener and add it to the `List<View>`, nothing will get lost. Only thing is you won't know each view's actual type.

Comment: Thanks @ronginat, so is there a method to achieve the true class?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce no

Comment: When you add a specific type of view to a `List<View>` what you are declaring is "I don't care about the specific type of this view". If that's untrue then don't it. If you find yourself having to cast the item when you retrieve it from the list then that is evidence that you do care about the specific types.

Comment: But using different lists may not be the right solution, perhaps. Are there other solutions? Maybe an Hashmap `<Class, List<View>>`?

Comment: every time when somebody decides to create a lot of different views manually it means the person doing something wrong...especially if it requires to put all these views in List

Comment: Why @Eugene? I can't use the xml hardcoding for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You biggest doubt here is

> Method implementation in ImageButton or ImageView (Like onClick or some other event), is lost when I convert it to a View object?

NO, this does not happen.

Consider two classes

```
class Parent{
    void big(){}
}
```

and

```
class Child extends Parent{
    void small(){}
}
```

If you say

```
Child c = new Child();
```

then you can use

`c.big();` as well as `c.small();`

but if you say

```
Parent c = new Child();
```

you are allowed to use

```
c.big();
```

But for calling `small()` inside `Child` class
you need to cast it

```
Child ch = (Child)c;
ch.small();
```

Now if there a number of subclasses, each with different methods available to them which
like `Child1` with `small1()` and `Child2` with `small2()` and so on then you can use `instanceof` for casting

like

```
if(ch1 instanceof Child1)
{   
    Child1 c1 = (Child1)ch1;
    c1.small1();
}
if(ch2 instanceof Child2)
{
    Child2 c2 = (Child2)ch2;
    c2.small2();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I like a lot your answer because you explain in the details what i doubt. I Want to mark it as correct answer, but i want to ask your opionion if `List<View> `can be the correct way to implements it.

Comment: It depends on a number of things. It is good to use the generic form like `List<View>`. Generics allow having a level of abstraction, which would otherwise be lost.

Comment: Yeah it's a lot of View objects( 100+ ), thanks a lot for the response. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The list only holds references of your components. If you create an `ImageButton` for exmaple, set a click listener and add it to the `List<View>`, nothing will get lost. Only thing is you won't know each view's actual type.

To get the true class of a generic `View` you can use multiple `if` statements that check all of your component types, like:

```
if (view instanceof ImageButton) {
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)view;
}
```

[instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526896/10470378) checks if an object is of a specific class or extends it. So make sure you first check for `ImageButton` before `ImageView` for example, because its a descendant of the class.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. Today i will try your solution, i let you know in the day.