# Is downcasting/isinstance wrong when programming to an interface?

Tags: oop, interface

I want to say "if a function takes a `B`, then directly calling a method that `B` does not have is an error".

This seems like an obvious statement in terms of programming to an interface. But what about downcasting? Consider the following Python code.

```
class C:
    ...

class B:
    def b_func() -> C:
        ...

class A(B):
    def a_func() -> C:
        ...

def f(b: B) -> C
    if isinstance(b, A):
        return b.a_func()
    else:
        return b.b_func()
```

At runtime, the call to `b.a_func()` is perfectly fine because we checked the runtime type, so in that sense it is not an error. However, this feels very wrong in terms of programming to the `B` interface. In what sense is calling a method that `B` does not have an error, even if the instance of `B` happens to have a runtime type that does have that method? What would be the name of that kind of error? Or is my intuition completely wrong?

Comment: Related: [Justified `instanceof`? Using it with an interface but not an implementation type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314495/1371329)