# Identify an object in an arraylist

Tags: java

So, i am making an eshop in java, but I am facing a problem that I can't solve. The eshop sells 4 items, so we have the class Item and the subclasses Pen, Pencil, Notebook and Paper and I have stored them all in an arraylist. I want to make a method, which prints the products in categories according the type of the object that they are. For example:
Pen -> pen1, pen2
Pencil-> pencil1,pencil2

The problem that I have is that I don't know how to recognise in the arraylist that for example pen1 is a pen object and print it at the pen category. I tried to use an iterator, but i am not very familiar with it, so i couldn't do much.

Comment: Try looking at the `instanceof` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instanceof-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory Java Streams solution:

```
Map<Class<? extends Item>, List<Item>> map = yourList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));
```

This groups the list by class, resulting in a map with each class as a key and a list of objects of that class as value.

In order to get all pencils:

```
List<? extends Item> pencils = map.get(Pencil.class);
```

---

#### `getClass()`

Retrieves the class of the instance.

```
Pencil myItem = new Pencil();
myItem.getClass(); // Returns Class[com.example.yourpackage.Pencil]
```

#### `instanceof`

`myItem instanceof Item` checks if the variable `myItem` is an *instance of* the `Item` class, that means either an `Item`, or one of its subclasses, for example `Pencil`. The comparison, of course, returns a `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you already have something like this:

```
interface Item {...}
class Pen implements Item {...}
class Pencil implements Item {...}
class Notebook implements Item {...}
class Paper implements Item {...}
```

And somewhere in the application there is an `ArrayList`:

```
 List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
 items.add(new Pen("pen1"));
 items.add(new Pencil("pencil1"));
 items.add(new Pen("pen2")); 
 items.add(new Paper("paper1"));
```

So in order to print only, say Pen-s you can use the following code:

```
private void printWithForEachLoop(List<Item> list, Class<? extends Item> cl) {
   for(Item item : list) {
        if(cl.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

If you can use streams (java 8+), you can have the following implementation:

```
 private void printWithStreams(List<Item> list, Class<? extends Item> cl) {
       list.stream().filter( o -> 
         cl.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())).forEach(System.out::println);
 }
```

Another way is using the `instanceof` operator, but it requires you to 'hardcode' the class name, for example in case of streams you can do:

```
items.stream().filter( o -> o instanceof Pen).forEach(System.out::println);
```