# JPanel removeAll doesn't get rid of previous components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a swing application in which I display images in a JPanel. If the app is unable to produce the image I want to remove the previous one from the JPanel and replace it with a JTextField and message. I can add the text field , but it's drawn on top of the previous contents, which is itself a subclass of JPanel. Here's what I have:

```
private void displayMessage(String message) {
  JTextField tf = new JTextField(message);
  cdPanel.removeAll();
  cdPanel.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);//tried lots of variations, inc. no layout    
  cdPanel.validate();
}
```

How can I get cdPanel to completely redraw itself?

Comment: Had you tried calling `cdPanel.revalidate(); cdPanel.repaint()` instead of `cdPanel.validate()` ? Moreover, how are images displayed on this `JPanel`? Are you using `JLabel` or drawing them directly on the `JPanel` ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw thanks, that works perfectly. Please post so I can mark yours as the answer :-)

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) But Please from next time, try to provide the information to the fullest, as if you are explaining it to a child, as to __What you doing ?__, __What you expecting ?__ and __What exactly happened ?__ This way, the person who is answering will be able to provide better insight regarding the given situation :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can simply try calling :

```
cdPanel.revalidate();
cdPanel.repaint();   // This is required in some cases
```

instead of

```
cdPanel.validate();
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are dealing with unpredictable latency, use a `SwingWorker` to do the loading in the background, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513). The example uses `pack()` to resize the label to that of the image, but you may want to use a fixed-size grid and scale the images, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15961412/230513).