# Java applet layout and action handler issue

Tags: java, swing

In my application ,When the user clicks the JButton, display a JLabel that prompts the user to enter an integer, a JTextField into which the user can type the integer, and a secondJButton that contains the text Double me. When the user clicks the second button, the integer is doubled and the answer is displayed in the JTextField.

I am not able to display second button and text fields, when i click first button...please help

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class JDouble extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private Container container = getContentPane();

    /**
     * The JButton.
     */
    private JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
    private JButton button2 = new JButton("Double me");

    /**
     * The JLabel.
     */
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Integer");
    private JTextField textfield = new JTextField(4);
    private JTextField textfield2 = new JTextField(4);

    public void init() {
        // set the layout to FlowLayout
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // register the 'this' action listener for the button
        button.addActionListener(this);

        container.add(button);
    }

    public void init1(){
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        container.add(textfield);
        container.add(button2);
        container.add(textfield2);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        container.add(label);
    }

    public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String me = textfield.getText();
        int computation = Integer.parseInt(me);
        computation = computation*2;
        String changecomputation = Integer.toString(computation);
        textfield2.setText(changecomputation);
        container.remove(button);

        container.add(label);

        repaint();
        validate();
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, having function names like `init1` and `actionPerformed1` probably aren't helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your init() method:

```
   public void init() {  
        // set the layout to FlowLayout
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        // register the 'this' action listener for the button
        button.addActionListener(this);
        container.add(button);
}
```

We'll use this function to show the other fields when 'Click Me' is clicked...

```
  private showInputFields(){
        container.add(textfield);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        container.add(button2);
        container.add(textfield2);
  }
```

Let's fix your action listener. If you want 'Click Me" button displayed on startup, `init()` takes care of that. When user clicks 'Click Me', we invoke `showInputFields()` to display the other components; we handle 'Double me' click using the same listener, we just check event source to handle appropriately...

```
    private boolean inputFieldsDisplayed; 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if( actionEvent.getSource() == button && !inputFieldsDisplayed){
            showInputFields();
            inputFieldsDisplayed = true;

        } else if ( actionEvent.getSource() == button2){                
            String me = textfield.getText();
            int computation = Integer.parseInt(me);
            computation = computation*2;
            String changecomputation = Integer.toString(computation);
            textfield2.setText(changecomputation);                
        }
        validate();
        repaint();            
    }
```

Comment: but two buttons appearing at the same time..what should i do.whein i click the button1..button2,textfield1,textfield2 appears?

Comment: when i click it other controls should appear

Comment: @raffian : `validate()/revalidate()` should come before `repaint()`, why is the need to `repaint()` if nothing has changed. That's why we `revalidate()/validate()` first so the Layout Manager concern lays out the components, then we call `repaint()` to make those changes appear nicely :-)

Comment: @raffian : Please have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9510125/1057230) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18001087/1057230)