# How can I add and remove components in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I have a `LinkedList` of `JPanel`s which are shown inside a main `JPanel`.

How can I change these panels and refresh my main panel?

For example, if I want to use a search method and show only `3` of these `JPanel`s and another time it show `10` `JPanels`, how can I do it?

Comment: Add/remove the JPanel(s) and call `revalidate` and`repaint`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically remove Component from JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117332/dynamically-remove-component-from-jpanel)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [mcve].

Comment: This sounds better suited to a `JList` (that potentially uses a `JPanel` as the renderer)..